# GitLab bot name as **** in both API and web

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to understand why GitLab doesn't show bot names in comments, so I tried to use the API and get a comment on an MR that came from a bot. The relevant part of the returned JSON is:

```py
'author': {'id': 12345,
   'username': 'project_123456_bot',
   'name': '****',
   'state': 'active',
   'avatar_url': '...',
   'web_url': '...'
},
```

where `name` is `"****"`, which is also displayed in the MR comments. But if I get the bot user itself, I get:

```
> bot
<User id: 12345>
> bot.bot
True
> bot.name
'Mr. Robot'
```

So the name *is* there, but for some reason in the MR comments it's shown as `****`. However, the popup on hovering the `****` in comments reveals the real name.

Is there a way to show the name in MR comments and also via API directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an upstream bug

Issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/347307

MR: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/81472

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that your bot name matches one of your [masked project or group variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#mask-a-cicd-variable), and GitLab is obfuscating the string in the output logs.

Comment: There is no variable in the project where the bot comments.

Comment: Might it be a Group Variable or even a [Server Instance Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-an-instance) then? Anyway, this behavior of replacing a string with *** strongly looks like masked variables protection.

Comment: Found out it's a upstream bug actually